# How do I calculate the mean square error

Tags: c#, math, statistics, linear-algebra

I have the following code that I managed to piece together:

```
private void CalcMSE(List<Point> data)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

       foreach (Point item in data)
       {
          double difference = item.m_x - item.m_y;
          sum = sum + difference * difference;
       } 
    double mse = sum / x;  //<-- Don't know what x should be!
    Console.WriteLine("The mean square error is {0}",mse) ;
}
```

the inputs are :

```
point.m_x = 3;
point.m_y = 1;
pointList.Add(point);

point.m_x = 4;
point.m_y = 4;
pointList.Add(point);

point.m_x = 5;
point.m_y = 6;
pointList.Add(point);

point.m_x = 6;
point.m_y = 6;
pointList.Add(point);

point.m_x = 8;
point.m_y = 10;
pointList.Add(point);
```

According to those in the know the MSE should be 0.77 and MSR 40.89

But I have no idea what the "formula" for x is (see code comment).

Can anyone assist me who knows anything about linear regression?

here's what the ouputs should be

[image: desired ouput]

Comment: What about `d.Count()` ?

Comment: data.Count () or Lenght... or take one count variable increment it by one in for loop. x will be equal to count.

Comment: Are you sure...? It gives a value of 8 for d.Count()

Comment: No. Vivek nuna is right, I got confused and wrote the wrong list.  It should be data.Count().

Comment: That "d" list seems to be useless, though.

Comment: Silly me as well. Let me try with data

Comment: give 1.8... are you guys sure that the formula is correct. Im going to edit my question with the "source" picture

Comment: based on the edit this seems to be just linear regression. So basically minimizing the mean squared error across all points using a linear formula y = (ax+b) with a selected a and b to fit these requirements. So in other words just taking the difference of x and y and squaring them and getting the mean isn't the right approach here I think.

Comment: Its been a while since I done math.. lol..

Comment: It is clear that `x` is the number of items in the list = `data.Count()`. If math are so far, take a look to that [Wiki - Mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should always create a new point before adding to the list `point = new Point(x,y)`, I don't think list.add creates a copy.

as for the x, I think `data.Count()` will do